# MySQL CASE Statement Issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I attempt to retrieve a valid team image from a table of images. There should only ever be one team image validated. The below case statement works great when the first image received is also validated, but if the first image is invalidated and the second received is validated... I get a NULL string

```
CASE
    WHEN taskcode = 0 AND validated = 1
    THEN imgRenamed
    ELSE NULL
    END AS teamImg
```

to summarize in another way.

1. one team image received and validated (above works fine)
2. one team image received, invalidated (above works fine)
3. same as #2, but second image received and validated (above returns NULL)

I should also note that both images in question will have a taskcode of 0, it's just that one will be marked invalid and the second marked valid.

Is this enough information for someone to help me understand what's gone wrong in case #3?

thanks

Comment: The `CASE` statement isn't used to select which rows get returned, that's done in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Please show your table structure and your full SELECT query. Then it will be easier to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include this in an aggregation, something like:

```
select max(CASE WHEN taskcode = 0 AND validated = 1
                THEN imgRenamed
                ELSE NULL
           END) AS teamImg
from . . .
group by teamId
```

Without the aggregation, MySQL chooses arbitrary values typically from one row for the conditions.  In other words, the conditions are not being applied across all rows, just to one of them.